# How do I get this to encode properly?

Tags: python, xml, encoding, utf-8, python-3.x

I have a XML file with Russian text:

```
<p>все чашки имеют стандартный посадочный диаметр - 22,2 мм</p>
```

I use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to do manipulate it in various ways (without ever touching the text content). Then, I use `ElementTree.tostring`:

```
info["table"] = ET.tostring(table, encoding="utf8") #table is an Element
```

Then I do some other stuff with this string, and finally write it to a file

```
f = open(newname, "w")
output = page_template.format(**info)
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

I wind up with this in my file:

```
<p>\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5 \xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x8e\xd1\x82 \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x87\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x80 - 22,2 \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbc</p>
```

How do I get it encoded properly?

Comment: You mean there are literal backslashes in the file? Or is this the representation of a python `bytes` object? That would be correct.

Comment: @mata: This is what is literally in my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```
 info["table"] = ET.tostring(table, encoding="utf8")
```

which returns `bytes`. Then later you apply that to a format string, which is a `str` (unicode), if you do that you'll end up with a representation of the bytes object.

etree can return an unicode object instead if you use:

```
 info["table"] = ET.tostring(table, encoding="unicode")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ElementTree.tostring returns a binary object and not an actual string. The answer to this is:

```
info["table"] = ET.tostring(table, encoding="utf8").decode("utf8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - with output parameter being just the Russian string without utf-8 encoding.

```
import codecs
#output=u'все чашки имеют стандартный посадочный диаметр'
with codecs.open(newname, "w", "utf-16") as stream: #or utf-8
    stream.write(output + u"\n")
```

Comment: it's python3, no need for the `u` prefix to strings. it'll even cause an error on versions before 3.3.